# Files generated with precompile are not compiled

Tags: .net-core

During `dotnet build`, it seems that generated files created during the precompile tasks are not used and the build failed.

`precompile` cannot be used for files generation? The documention is pretty light about it.

or do I have to deal with a delay to be sure that files are correctly writed on disk ?

Project.json:

```
{
  "name": "Service",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "precompile": "%project:Directory%/protogen.bat"
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't have this problem anymore, but to save time for anyone running into this issue, here is what is going on:

The problem is a bug in the `dotnet` tool where source files generated by a `precompile` command aren't included in the list of files to compile. See [#1475](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1475) and [#3807](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3807).

It was fixed by [PR#4680](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/pull/4680). Upgrading to a newer version of .NET Core should fix it.